# Java: Invalid type code 05 / a Socket's OutputStream

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I am trying to encrypt a Socket's ObjectOutputStream. But somehow, when I try to decrypt / encrypt it, I get a **java.io.StreamCorruptedException**

My encrypt / decrypt methods: (those methods are not mine, I found them on stackoverflow)

```
/**
 * Encrypt a object and write it to the given outstream
 * @param object the serializable object
 * @param ostream The outstream
 */
private void encrypt(Serializable object, OutputStream ostream) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
    try {
        SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(key, transformation);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(transformation);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks);
        SealedObject sealedObject = new SealedObject(object, cipher);

        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(ostream, cipher);
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(cos);
        outputStream.writeObject(sealedObject);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Decrypt a object from the given InputStream
 * @param istream the inputstream
 * @return the decrypted object
 */
private Object decrypt(InputStream istream) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
    SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(key, transformation);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(transformation);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks);

    CipherInputStream cipherInputStream = new CipherInputStream(istream, cipher);
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(cipherInputStream);
    SealedObject sealedObject;
    try {
        sealedObject = (SealedObject) inputStream.readObject();
        return sealedObject.getObject(cipher);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}
```

So I tried it, and I also looked my question up already, and I found out that it has got something to do with duplicate **ObjectOutputStream**s, but how can I then write my Object from the **CipherOutputStream** without creating a new **ObjectOutputStream** / read my Object from the **CipherInputStream** without creating a new **ObjectInputStream**?

Comment: General advice: **Always use a fully qualified Cipher string.** `Cipher.getInstance("AES");` may result in different ciphers depending on the default security provider. It most likely results in `"AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"`, but it doesn't have to be. If it changes, you'll lose compatibility between different JVMs.

Comment: **Never use [ECB mode](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14487/13022)**. It's deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. You should at the very least use a randomized mode like [CBC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22260/13022) or [CTR](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2378/13022). It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.